# Is 'The mouse was out the cheese-box' natural?

Tags: meaning

> Examples  in  which  a  single preposition substitutes for a whole
> sequence are difficult to find. This is mainly  because  prepositions
> typically  require  a  complement,  but  also because  in  standard
> written  English  there  is  a  contrast  between  **in** for location and
> **into** for movement, and for many speakers there is a contrast between **out
> of** for movement and **out** for location, as in (14).
>
> (14)
>
> 1. The cat was sleeping in the kitchen.
> 2. The cat trotted into the kitchen.
> 3. The mouse jumped out of the cheese-box.
> 4. The mouse was out the cheese-box.

Because 'is' is not a verb of movement, is 'The mouse was out of the cheese-box.' equal to 'The mouse was out the cheese-box.'?

And with a verb of movement,'get out of here' means they are telling you to leave the place where you are and 'get out here' means they are saying "come out here with us". So, is 'get out here' more informal in that it has the meaning of 'get out of there and come here'?

Comment: Standard syntax is *[subject] [verb] **out of** [container].* The second preposition *(**of**)* is often discarded in informal contexts *(I threw it out the window, The mouse got out the box, He walked out the door)* - but I think you're right that we're far less likely to drop ***of*** if the verb doesn't involve movement. Whatever the reason, #4 is at the very least "marked, non-standard" without ***of***.

Comment: ...but note that imperative *Get **out** there!* and *Get **out of** there!* have different meanings. The first demands that you ***go to*** that location (neither speaker nor addressee are currently there). The second demands that you ***leave*** that location (addressee is currently there, but not speaker).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is *get out there/here* informal?

Comment: Well, it's an imperative usage, so I can't easily imagine a "formal" context (written *or* spoken) where you'd be likely to encounter *Get out there!* But like I said, including ***of*** changes the meaning completely, so it's effectively meaningless to contrast the "with / without **of**" alternatives as "formal / informal".

Comment: It seems odd to informally and casually omit 'of' and formally hyphenate 'cheese-box'.

Comment: As a Brit, omitting 'of' always sounds more American, though I don't think that's an absolute.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You can give an answer.

Comment: @DoneWithThis.: I wasn't aware of that, but [this AmE usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out+the+window%2Cout+of+the+window&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) and [this BrE chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out+the+window%2Cout+of+the+window&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) show a clear difference. Specifically, ***out the window*** has massively overtaken ***out of the window*** in AmE over the past half-century. BrE is moving in the same direction, but the version with ***of*** is still dominant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To strictly indicate location with no suggestion of movement, your sentence (4) is unnatural.

In some non-standard varieties of English (I'm thinking central United States), the structure *[ "be out" + location ]* can be used to indicate having recently exited a location:

> (*on the phone*) OK, I'm walking down the hall, and I'm opening the front door, and now **I'm out** the house.

In standard varieties of English, this would be phrased "*...out **of** the house.*"

"Out" can also be used to mean movement out from the object (including in standard varieties of English), as in:

> When he saw the cat, the mouse was out the cheese box, across the room and into its hole in a flash.

However it would be more natural to say "*...out **of** the cheese box...*"

The only natural way I can think of to use "out" as a preposition in a standard variety of English is in the idiomatic expression, *to be "out the door"*, roughly meaning to have started going to some destination starting from inside a building:

> *(also on the phone)* I'm out the door and I'll be there in 45 minutes.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out):

> **out** *preposition*
> used as a function word to indicate an outward movement
> *ran out the door
>
> looked out the window*

That is the only definition for "out" as a preposition in that dictionary, so any other use of "out" as a preposition is very uncommon.

Comment: So, whether is 'Look at the tree from out the house', or' Look at the tree from outside the house' natural?  I mean that 'out' just indicates the location not otherwise.

Comment: Only "*...from outside the house...*" is natural for all English speakers. There may also be speakers of some non-standard varieties of English to whom the other sentence is natural, but I can't say for sure. I've added more info to the end of my question

Answer (score 1):

In American English, one is more likely to say, "The horses are out the gate," *sans* "of", or "He let the cat out,"  But, "The mouse was out the cheese-box," does not sound natural.

It is also somewhat ambiguous.

- If used as in, "He was out the money," it implies the mouse paid for but lost the cheese-box. [Admittedly unlikely, unless in juvenile literature.]
- It could also mean (perhaps as intended), that, "the mouse had escaped the cheese-box." [Difficult, with a full stomach.]

Comment: With 'The mouse was out the cheese-box', why isn't there a meaning that the mouse is outside the cheese-box? You know I don't mean the mouse got out of the box, but it is outside the box.

Comment: Then, in AmE, one *would* say, "The mouse was outside the cheese-box."